# enable all cells delete button without swipe gesture

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to implement a `UITableView` using core data and when I press a Trash button in my ViewController, I can see all the delete buttons on the right of all the cells without the swipe gesture. But When i enabled the editing mode only Delete Button should have to be displayed on the right side

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove note from table view
        [self.notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

can anyone suggest me how it is possible

Comment: if you want to do UITableView is go in editing mode when you tapped on button then follow my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited :**
Write Following Code :

```
-(void) yourMethodName:(UIButton *) sender
{
       if(self.editing)
        {
            [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
            [self.tblView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
            [self.tblView reloadData];

        }
        else
        {
            [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            [self.tblView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            [self.tblView reloadData];

        }
}
```

Comment: Don't u think , this code will show minus button on the left side of cell instead of delete button on the right side.

Comment: but OP need to "enable all cells delete button without swipe gesture" so i put this code for do it by button

Comment: check my edited answer,  put this code in you button (delete) method

Comment: Yes iPatel UITableView goes in editing mode but it would be shown without the red left circle Button

Comment: iPatel Red Delete Button of all cells  should be enable on the right when i tap on my delete button. is this possible

Comment: @iPatel waiting your kind response and another suggestion